# VBA-How to convert a local path of a file in a folder managed by Drive File Stream into an URL

Tags: vba, google-drive-api

My goal is to create an xls sheet containing a list of files (file name + link to the file) contained in a folder.

This folder is a GDrive synchronized folder (using Drive File Stream)

I have a VBA macro which is producing this list of files but the link is a local link (G:...) and not an URL link (https://drive.google.com/...) that can be used outside my computer.

Here is an exemple
Let say I have a file in my "Drive File Stream" folder like this one:

```
G:\Team Drives\Test\my_file.txt
```

How to convert this path (using excel vba) into a GDrive's URL:

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/FILE_ID/edit?usp=sharing
```

Another way to ask is how to get the file_id from a local path?

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43463046/edit) the question to be on-topic: include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have edited the question to be more specific on the goal